# when a barcode scanner create a com port and when not?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I m absolutely beginner on the topic barcode scanner.

I have the following scanner now:

Scanner1:
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08RDRGK4X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1

Scanner2:
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0736NNZNV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

When I plug scanner1 I don't see in the device manager that a com port is created. But with scanner 2 yes.

Could someone explain to me why ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a different product from a different vendor.
It is at the vendor's discretion what to do with the connection method and API.

Many vendors often support both connection methods and APIs, but which one is the default depends on the vendor's policy.
In some cases, they are distinguished by the difference in model number and branch number.

It's possible that the model you chose happened to be its connection method and API.

---

**In Addition:**

However, there is a high possibility that the barcode scanner1 does not have the function to connect with a serial port.

If there is such a feature, the [user's manual](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8lrrhjvop8x721/TR-UM010-EN-ZQ-2021.8.11-S01-EV.pdf) has a setting barcode to change the mode, but it is not.

[product page](https://tera-digital.com/products/tera-barcode-scanner-wireless-1d-with-stand-high-2500-pixel-precise-resolution-2-in-1-2-4g-wireless-and-usb-wired-can-scan-screen-1d-barcodes-for-bar-code-reader-for-store-supermarket-model-8200)

Comment: thank you, I understand that the scanner support that or that connection method or both but do you know how I can make it that Scanner1 create a com port ?

Comment: From my personal experience some application will refuse to work as their setup **expect** a designated COM-Port to use. So some vendors will provide a emulated COM-Ports which is then setup with their specific driver.